# how to embed chart with API into another webpage

Tags: html, api, birt

I'm really new to BIRT report developer. Right now, I need to get the API from my chart, which was created in a report, and past it to another web page. But, I really don't know how to do that, can anyone help me solve my problem?

I'm using BIRT PRO, and the only code I can get is from the XML source. I have to submit the report next week, so I'm very nervous. I will greatly appreciate for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to view content from the BIRT report in a browser you can do any of the following:

- Deploy the BIRT runtime viewer with Tomcat - http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2014/12/deploy-birt-viewer-for-tomcat/.
- Download the free F-Type server and put your BIRT report there, then you can use the "interactive viewer" web interface to show the entire report or use the JavaScript API to embed the entire report or just parts of the report in a web page. http://birt.actuate.com/products/birt-ihub-ftype
- Run the report from BIRT Designer Professional and export the report as HTML content.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But what's the "interactive viewer", how can I find it. Could you give me more details about it?@user3660637

Comment: BIRT reports support a free and commercial viewer. The commercial viewer is called "interactive viewer" and contains page navigation, menu options such as export, and enables you to change report elements while viewing the report such as filter data, change a chart type. This commercial viewer is what you see in F-Type when you load a report in a browser. You can also see this viewer when you load the entire report using the JavaScript API or if you preview the report in BIRT Designer Pro. Using the JavaScript API you can also choose to disable that viewer or to extend it with HTML elements.